# how to fix my ipv6 arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, ipv6

I've been having problems with NPM giving an error saying there's a problem with my connection.

When I go to https://test-ipv6.com/index.html.en_US, it says `No IPv6 address detected`

How would I go about setting up my ipv6(or fixing it, since `ip addr` seems to show that i already have an ipv6.

I'm on Arch-Linux BTW

Comment: Is this an issue of a public vs a private IP? That site will check your public IP, and your computer will see private IP, most likely.

Comment: Does `ip addr` show that you have a _global_ IPv6 address? (Currently, global addresses always start with a `2`. The ones starting with an `f` are definitely non-global – they're either private addresses, or link-local addresses that every host has.)